# rotated thumbnail created using ffmpeg

Tags: php, android, ios, video, ffmpeg

I am creating a thumbnail from video using ffmpeg with following command

```
$command = "$ffmpegpath -i $TempSrc -an -ss 00:00:01 -r 1 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg -y $output_image_path";
exec($command);
```

Image is created successfully but with different orientation from the video.
I recorded video from iPad in portrait view and uploaded it  and image is created in landscape side .Cant figure out what went wrong in the command. I also tried `exif_read_data` php function but it does not return any orientation value.

NOTE: I have provided the correct values for $ffmpegpath and $output_image_path

Comment: I have a possible explanation for this issue, but it is only a guess without more info from you. Please include the complete console output/log from the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: having the same issue, could you resolve it? Thanks!